# How to push an object into an array in async function

Tags: node.js

i have been trying to insert an object into an array in async function ,but it
return an empty array as output  in nodejs ,mongoose

```
var data = [];

app.get("/api/post", async (req, res) => {
  const post = await UserPost.find();

  post.forEach(async element => {
    const email = await element.userid;
    const user = await Account.find({ email });
    const usern = await user[0].username;

    var userobject = {
      element,
      usern
    };
    //Promise.all(userobject)
    data.push(userobject);
  });

  console.log(data);

  res.send({ data });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are struggling with promises. In order to achieve this specific scenario, you can use `Promise.all` and  `Array.map`.

Here is a code I edited for you:

(*please note that this is just a dummy code for the sake of explanation)

```
app.get("/api/post", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await dummyPromiseResolver(); // first promise

    const promises = posts.map(async element => {
      const user = await dummyEmailReturn(element.userid); // second promise
      const usern = user[0].username;
      return {
        usern,
        ...element
      };
    });

    const fresult = await Promise.all(promises);
    res.send(fresult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error in posts fetch:" + error);
  }
});
```

If I describe this code, posts.map is creating an Array of promises since we need to iterate through every object in the array and needs to add values from separate promises.

Then `Promise.all` can execute your promise array and return final results array with your desired results.

**Note:** You can also use `for … of` as well but when we need to happen things parallelly we use `Promise.all`. You can find more information from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

here is a link for code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/serverless-cookies-nu4h0

Please note that I have added `dummyPromiseResolver` and `dummyEmailReturn` which would be equal to `UserPost.find()` and `Account.find()` functions respectively. In addition to that, I removed a few unnecessary awaits in your code. I added a try catch block to catch any exceptions. You can change that try catch as you please.

hope this will help you. let me know if you need more clarifications.